# select columns dynamically based on list of column names obtained from

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I need to do a simple select statement, but based on a list of column names that is dynamic and filtered to the be just the lower case column names in the table. The table structure is out of my control and frequently varies.  It is not possible for me to know any column names before hand - only that there are UPPER CASE names (not wanted) and lower case names (wanted).

the_table:

```
COL_UPPERCASE_1 COL_UPPERCASE_2 col_lowercase_1 col_lowercase_2
data1           data2           data3           data4
data5           data6           data7           data8
```

I can get a list of the column names I want using this:

```
select group_concat(column_name) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'the_database' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'the_table' AND column_name = BINARY LOWER(column_name));
```

which returns the list of columns that I want:

```
+---------------------------------+
| group_concat(column_name)       |
+---------------------------------+
| col_lowercase_1,col_lowercase_2 |
+---------------------------------+
```

My question: How do I effectively insert the results of that query into my select statement?  E.g.

```
select <column list from above "select group_concat..." query> from my_table;
```

Specifically, in the example above, I want the equivalent of:

```
select col_lowercase_1,col_lowercase_2 from the_table;
```

to return:

```
+---------------------------------+
| col_lowercase_1 col_lowercase_2 |
+---------------------------------+
| data3           data4           |
| data7           data8           |
+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec()` to run a query from some text

E.g.

```
declare @Columns VARCHAR(8000);
select @Columns = select group_concat(column_name) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'the_database' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'the_table' AND column_name = BINARY LOWER(column_name));
exec ( 'select ' + @columns ' from the_table' );
```